# MongoDB Gridfs NODE display image

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm storing images from angular application in MongoDB using GridFS. I have a problem while getting images from database. I can only display images in iexplorer and postman.In chrome, firefox it looks like corrupted image.
Is there any way to display images in angular directly from database? I'm using express. And try to insert image like this:`<img src="upload/55a75dbb749062041b4c84ba"/>`

My router

```
  router.get('/upload/:objectId',function(req, res){

   var options = {
        _id : req.params.objectId
    };

    gfs.exist(options, function(err, exists) {
        if(!exists) {
            res.status(404);
            res.end();
        } else {
             res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
            var readstream = gfs.createReadStream(options);
            readstream.pipe(res);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

```
    router.get('/upload/:image',function(req, res){

    try{
        var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({ filename: req.params.image});
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        readstream.pipe(res);  

    }
    catch (err) {
        log.error(err);
        return next(errors.create(404, "File not found."));
    }


});
```

html:

```
 <img src="/usr-rest/users/upload/here_goes_id">
```